# How to fix DB that is searching for rows and updating slowly

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently facing some issues with a table in my DB and I was wondering if anybody has some suggestions on how to do it better.

There is a table in my DB that is being updated every 5 seconds, which is needed. (UPDATE queries on a specific ID) About 200 rows are being updated every 5 seconds (These are all single update statements) whilst also adding about 100 rows to this DB every 5 seconds (INSERT statements, also single statements). On top of that I'm also fetching quite a lot of data from this schema at times (SELECT statement that can fetch about 50k rows). This is not very frequent but when I execute this query, it can take upwards of 40(!) seconds.

If I run the big query locally (the one going for 50k rows), it usually takes about 0.8 seconds or less. But that DB is also only for local testing and is not experiencing as much load as the production one.

As you can see in the image below, some updates are taking over 100 seconds, which is not ideal. Also it's searching for rows to update, whilst there are about 2 million rows in the DB and it's looking for a specific ID but it's still quite slow.

are these all just plain query issues? Or am I missing something?
I would like to look into how I can solve some of these issues and make the DB perform better. If anyone could give me some pointers that would be much appreciated as I'm quite new to DB optimizing. Thank you very much.

If this question is not correctly asked, please also let me know. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Show us the `UPDATE` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

Show us the `UPDATE` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  With that, we can judge whether you have the optimal `INDEX`.

Is the disk HDD, not SSD?  This is a rare case where a hardware upgrade is an obvious answer to performance.

Assuming that you have a a good index and cannot upgrade, then here is my answer.

- Collect the needed updates in a table.  Ditto for the inserts.  (I can't tell at the moment whether this can be done in a single table or needs two tables.  No big deal either way.)
- Have a continually running script that transfers all the collected rows into the real table.
- To make the above practical (and faster), ping-pong between a pair of tables.  More discussion:  [*High Speed Ingestion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table)

That technique has the advantage of becoming more efficient when there is a bigger backlog of updates and inserts to do.

To do a bulk Update, use

```
INSERT INTO real_table
        (uniq, col2, ...)
        SELECT uniq, col2, ... FROM update_staging_table
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        col2 = VALUES(col2), ...;
```

Where `uniq` is the unique column(s) on which you know which row to update.

The bulk Insert is simply

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO real_table
          (uniq, col2, ...)
    SELECT uniq, col2, ...
        FROM insert_staging_table;
```

If you have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, it is not included in the column lists above, but you do need to have a separate `UNIQUE` column.

Alternatively, the necessary Unique column is probably the `PRIMARY KEY`.

(Again, I need to see the schema.)

> SELECT statement that can fetch about 50k rows

This is also worth discussing.  Perhaps it can be sped up?  Perhaps you could build and maintain a "summary table" that would be much faster to fetch from?  Let's see the query.